# Firestore trigger function : Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firestore trigger. Its kicking up a bug. When I have the same syntax on other triggers. I don't understand whats wrong here- getting:

> Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path
>   must be a non-empty string.

This is my code:

```
exports.onIntroductionAdded = functions
.region("europe-west1")
.firestore.document(`/introductions/{introid}`)
.onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
  // const batch = db.batch();
  try { } catch(e){ }
```

In firebase console I get:

> onIntroductionAdded
>   Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string. at Object.validateResourcePath (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/path.js:407:15) at CollectionReference.doc (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1724:20) at doc.type.forEach (/srv/lib/index.js:225:70) at Array.forEach () at exports.onIntroductionAdded.functions.region.firestore.document.onCreate (/srv/lib/index.js:224:18) at  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)```

If it were a firebase firestore query, I would look at the path I'm passing in. though in this case I'm stumped as it looks like the wildcard implementation in the documentation.

Comment: Can you try what happens when you use regular single or double quotes for the path in the function declaration? So `.firestore.document('/introductions/{introid}')`.

Comment: Can you try dropping the leading slash? `introductions/{introid}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Have tried each of the above. Will try again once more (in case of propagation issues).

Comment: Ok, I've tried the following as suggested by @FrankvanPuffelen and @ChrisO

```
exports.onIntroductionAdded = functions
.firestore.document('/introductions/{id}')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  // const batch = db.batch();
  try {
return true;


exports.onIntroductionAdded = functions
.firestore.document("introductions/{id}")
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  // const batch = db.batch();
  try {
return true; 
```

Still getting the same error. Its bizarre. using: "firebase": "^6.3.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.1",

Comment: Looks like there's an issue for this in the firebase repo. No replies yet though. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/692

Comment: Thanks or sharing that. Hmm wonder if its a Firebase issue then (perhaps a server issue). My older functions work with the same logic.

Comment: Note that that issue already uses single quotes instead of backticks.

Comment: Hi Frank, I've used all 3 styles of quotes. Single, double and backtick. From speaking to firebase support, they are having issues with functions. It seems you can publish a topic in pub/sub for now until they fix the issue (their advice).